# How to copy datarow into a new datatable? - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to copy a DataRow into a new DataTable and then displaying it in GridView, But I keep having trouble with it.

```
Dim r As DataRow() = dt.Select("MacID = 'A06'")

Dim dt2 As DataTable
dt2.ImportRow(r) 'this is where problem begins

GridView2.DataSource = dt2
GridView2.DataBind()
```

The DataRow comes from another DataTable and when I hover my mouse to the problem line it says

```
Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Data.DataRow' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataRow'
```

For the life of me I have no idea what that means nor do I know if this is correct (which it probably isn't). Please help...

Edit 1:
Following *jmcilhinney*'s reply I tried  his 2nd code  because there are multiple rows. But I'm having some issues with the code:

```
Dim dt2 as DataTable

Dim rows = dt.Select("MacID = 'A06'")

        For Each row In rows
            dt2.ImportRow(row) 'Problem shown here
        Next

        GridView2.DataSource = dt2
        GridView2.DataBind()
```

Once again when I hover over it the error says:

```
Variable 'dt2' is used before it has been assigned a value.
A null reference exception could result at runtime.
```

Comment: As the error message indicates, you are not assigning anything to the `dt2` variable before calling its `ImportRow` method.  You declare the variable but never actually create a `DataTable` object and never add any columns to it. You'd have to either do that manually or call `Clone` on the existing `DataTable`.  Better to just create a `DataView` on the exist8ing `DataTable`, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: But I tried that already. Although it works on my GridView, my pie charts are still all messed up.

Comment: I don't do much, if any, charting so I'm not sure how a chart handles a `DataView` but I'd be surprised if it was any different to a `DataTable`. A `DataView` will definitely work for a `GridView` and that's what you asked about here.  If you have another question about using a `DataView` with a chart control then you should post that separately, or you can create another `DataTable` as I described.

Comment: Fair enough. I actually have that question posted. Is just that I was running some test and came across this issue and had to ask a this question to get answers. Yes, I'm that bad at programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataTable.Select` method returns an array of matching rows, not a single row.  `ImportRow` will import just a single row.  The specific solution to your problem depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

If you're trying to find a single row by key then you should call `Rows.Find` rather than `Select`, e.g.

```
Dim row = sourceTable.Rows.Find(keyValue)

If row IsNot Nothing
    destinationTable.ImportRow(row)
End If
```

If there may be multiple matches then use `Select` but you must loop through the resulting array, e.g.

```
Dim rows = sourceTable.Select(filterExpression)

For Each row In rows
    destinationTable.ImportRow(row)
Next
```

That said, do you really need another `DataTable`?  Can you not just create a `DataView` on the existing `DataTable`, e.g.

```
Dim view As New DataView(sourceTable,
                         filterExpression,
                         Nothing,
                         DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

A `DataView` can be bound wherever a `DataTable` can and, in fact, when you bind a `DataTable`, the data actually comes from the `DefaultView` property, which is type `DataView`.

Comment: I see. Then what can I use to allow multiple rows. Because `A06` should have 7 rows of data.

Comment: Because I need that DataTable for pie chart generation. If I just refer to the existing `DataTable`, it'll all become one jumbled up mess. The GridView is just for me to test if the data is correct only.

Comment: I have some additional issue which I edited above. Please take a look.